# how to display sub report in main page?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

```
Table
----------------------------------------
property |  Tenant  |  Types  |  Amount
----------------------------------------
p1            t1     Commercial   1000
p1            t1     Residential  1000
p1            t2     Commercial   1000
p1            t2     Residential  1000
p2            t1     Commercial   1000
p2            t1     Residential  1000
p2            t2     Commercial   1000
p2            t2     Residential  1000
---------------------------------------
```

I want to display like this in crystal report:

```
p1   t1
     --------------------
     |Commercial   1000 |
     |Residential  1000 |
     --------------------

p1   t2
     --------------------
     |Commercial   1000 |
     |Residential  1000 |
     --------------------

p2   t1
     --------------------
     |Commercial   1000 |
     |Residential  1000 |
     --------------------

p2   t2
     --------------------
     |Commercial   1000 |
     |Residential  1000 |
     --------------------
```

I want to display p1, t1, p2, t2 displayed in Main Page remaining thing from subeport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to add a cross-tab object to the report's header section.

[image]

Add Property, then Tenant to the Rows section; add Types to the Columns section; add Amount to the Summarized section.  You'll probably want to 'show labels', too:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a subreport for this; you can group your data so that it appears that way.

- Create a group for `property` (Group 1), and suppress the header and footer
- Create a group for `Tenant` (Group 2) below that.  Put the `property` and `Tenant` fields in the Group 2 header.
- Add your `Types` and `Amount` columns to the detail section.